# How do I connect JetBrains DataGrip to CockroachDB Serverless?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I'd like to use JetBrains DataGrip with CockroachDB Serverless.

How do I create a connection? I get errors that look like this:

```
[08004] FATAL: codeParamsRoutingFailed: missing cluster name in connection string.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following configuration to connect to CockroachDB Serverless from JetBrains DataGrip (or other JetBrains IDEs).

[image: General configuration panel]

The key tricky part is that you need to add the cluster name to the `options` parameter in the Advanced tab, as shown here. Replace `cluster-name-1234` with your cluster name and ID, as shown on your CockroachDB Serverless `Connect` screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

--cluster=  Identifies your tenant cluster on a multi-tenant host. For example, funny-skunk-123. This option is deprecated. hostThe in the connection string now includes the tenant information.[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2WNS.png)